# Angular2 DynamicContentLoader inserting element to top of the target container

Tags: typescript, angular

All three loadXXX() method seems just put the dynamic component to a target container. If my container already have components inside, how do i put new component to TOP of the existing components? (see example below)

e.g.

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

What I want:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>!!! Insert Here !!!!</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

- row is my component here

Comment: I don't fully understand the question. Do you want to insert a `<tr>...</tr>` row or do you want to insert a component inside the `<td>...</td>`?

Comment: i want to insert a component. The sample html is just for demonstrating about the position I want to insert to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a straight-forward solution but it might work for you

You can use a wrapper element like explained in [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) and use it like

```
<table>
  <tr dcl-wrapper *ngFor="let type of types" [type]="type"><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Existing Row</td></tr>
</table>
```

with a field in the component that holds references to the components you want to insert

```
class MyComponent {
  types = [MyCmp1, MyCmp2, MyCmp3];
}
```

this way the order of the components in the `types` array defines where the components are inserted.